# Python handling options and args

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-arguments, getopt

I have written a python code and I want to handle switches and arguments. So I want to tell script:

If you see `-u` then there is no `-d <name>` in arguments `print "sth"`:

```
if sys.argv=='-u' and sys.argv!='-d':
    print "You must use the -d switch!"
    sys.exit()
```

Seems this is wrong method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sys.argv` is a *list* so you'd have to test for membership:

```
if '-u' in sys.argv and '-d' not in sys.argv:
```

However, you'd be better of using the [`argparse` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) to handle command line interfaces for you. It won't handle interdependencies directly, but it is easy enough to extend the use and exit with a help message:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-u", action='store_true')
parser.add_argument("-d")
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.u and not args.d:
    parser.error('You must use the -d switch when setting -u!')
```

Demo:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument("-u", action='store_true')
_StoreTrueAction(option_strings=['-u'], dest='u', nargs=0, const=True, default=False, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.add_argument("-d")
_StoreAction(option_strings=['-d'], dest='d', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> args = parser.parse_args(['-u'])
>>> args.u
True
>>> args.d
>>> args.u and not args.d
True
>>> args = parser.parse_args(['-u', '-d', 'foo'])
>>> args.d
'foo'
>>> args.u and not args.d
False
```

Answer (score 1):

check if `u` **is**  in the list `sys.argv`  and `-d` **is not** in the list  `sys.argv`:

```
if '-u'  in  sys.argv and '-d'  not in sys.argv:
    print "You must use the -d switch!"
    sys.exit()
```